# Zeros of multivariable holomorphic functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, holomorphic-functions

Let $f $ be a holomorphic function of two variables such that for all complex $z $ we have $f (z, \bar {z})=0$. How can one prove that $f=0$ ?

Comment: No, your example is not holomorphic

Comment: Not holomorphic in y

Comment: This is the same problem !